# Trying to multiply out a value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a object that is given me a really small value and I want to multiply it by a number to see a larger change in the object on the X Axis.

```
var y = 10;

function initialize()
{

}

function On_finger1()
{

var positionArray = finger1.value.toArray();

// x y z = index0 index1 index2

// variable called currentZ which has taken the 3rd value
var currentX = positionArray[0];

currentX = y * 1000;

}
```

I am capturing the values from the array but it does not seem to be going to the object.

Comment: What is `finger1`?  What is `finger1.value`?  What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: So what's the question / problem? Side note, you're multiplying your `y` and assigning it to `currentX`, I'm assuming thats a typo?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the index in the array, you need to update the index of the array.

```
var currentX = positionArray[0];  //<--just getting the data that is in that index, it is not a pointer.

currentX = y * 1000;  //<--just overridding what was in the varaiable
```

What I think you want is just

```
positionArray[0] = y * 1000;
```

Comment: This might not even work.  If `toArray()` here is returning a copy of the data, this would just be updating a copy that gets thrown away.  We really need more context from the OP to figure out the correct solution.